# How to "take" a value -when it appears- to do something else?

Tags: javascript, string, getelementbyid

I´m starting to learn JS, so I have very basic questions about it...

In this case, I´m trying to do a "tennis points" counter. So, I made that, and when some player gets to 45 points, the app shows a "player 1 won the set"

The problem is... I want to take that "player 1 won the set", and when it appears, I want to show an alert saying "do you want to play another set?" But I can´t do it...

I have this blank

en HTML. I wrote the JS code, so when a player reaches 45 points, the

turns in "player 1 won the set"

```
            <p id="winner1"></p>
```

Then, I tried to "get" that new string and create an alert

```
let winner1 = document.getElementById("winner1")

if(winner1 == "player 1 won the set"){
alert("do you want to play another set?")
}
```

But it doesn´t work. I tried with winner1.value, but it doesn´t work either.
It seems like I need something that is always "listening" the

value, but I don´t know how to do it...

Sorry for the so basic question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just add the prompt for a new game to wherever you set `"player 1 won the set"`?

Comment: Hi! Actually, all of that was just an example. It´s not what I really want to do. But it was easier to explain with that example haha. I´m trying to get some text and then add a number in another section of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's a bad idea, but you could try this

```
if(winner1.innerText == "player 1 won the set"){
alert("do you want to play another set?")
}
```

#### It would be *much* better to avoid reading from the screen like this

Store the status in a variable, rather than inside the DOM. That would be simpler, more conventional, clearer for the programmer who maintains your code, and less vulnerable to bugs (e.g. when you change the wording of the screen message).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried "winner1.innerText" as well, but it didn´t work either =/

About the second part of your answer, I´m really sorry I´m not really sure if I got what you mean by "Store the status in a variable", or how to handle that. But I will check about it! I`m just starting to learning haha

Answer (score 0):

[`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) should work, But again it's not a good practice to compare the DOM `innerText` values to perform some operations. But if still if you want that in a same way, You can achieve like this **:**

```js
// Just for a demo purpose I am hardcoding this, But you update this variable as per the logic and then use this variable while checking for the condition to show the alert.
let winnerMessage = 'Player 1 won the set'

const msgElement = document.getElementById('winner1');
msgElement.innerText = winnerMessage;

if(winnerMessage === "Player 1 won the set"){
  alert("do you want to play another set?")
}
```

```html
<p id="winner1"></p>
```

More optimal and suggested solution is to bind the message along with the confirmation alert.

```js
let winnerMessage = 'Player 1 won the set'

if (winnerMessage) {
    alert(`${winnerMessage}, do you want to play another set?`);
}
```